# Dynamic naming for the output of pipe with group by, mutate, select

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to name a variable to save the output of a dplyr pipe where I input a dataframe and do a select. The name should be assigned according to a source_name variable that I assign separately combined with a constant.

```
source_name <- y
```

I can achieve that variable name on it's own by using the paste function.

```
paste(source_name, "constant", sep="_")
```

The output is correct with

```
y_constant
```

What I'm not getting is how to save the output of a dplyr pipe directly into that variable without creating the variable first. I would like to get

```
paste(source_name, "constant", sep="_") <- df %>% select(a,b,c)
```

without having to name the variable explicitly.

Comment: `assign(paste(source_name, "constant", sep="_"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `assign` here

```
assign( paste(source_name, "constant", sep="_"), df %>% select(a,b,c) )
```